# Proving existence of a matrix $X$ such that $A = BX$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, elementary-set-theory, vector-spaces

> Let $A = [\overrightarrow{v_1}... \overrightarrow {v_k}]$
>   and $B = [\overrightarrow{u_1}... \overrightarrow {u_k}]$
>   be $n\times k $ matrices
>
> Prove that if Span{$\overrightarrow{v_1},..., \overrightarrow {v_k}$} $\subseteq$ Span{$\overrightarrow{u_1},..., \overrightarrow {u_k}$} then there exists a matrix $X$ such that $A = BX$

so we have

$c_{i1} \overrightarrow{u_1} + ... + c_{ik} \overrightarrow{u_k} = v_i$ for $1\leq i\leq k$

substituting this into A gives us
$$ A = [(c_{11} \overrightarrow{u_1} + \space...\space + c_{1k} \overrightarrow{u_k}) \space...\space (c_{k1} \overrightarrow{u_1} + \space...\space + c_{kk} \overrightarrow{u_k})]$$

we see that we can write this in terms of coordinate vectors 
$$ A = [B[\overrightarrow{v_1}]_B\space...\space B[\overrightarrow{v_k}]_B]$$

that is $$ A = BX$$
where X is a $k \times k$ matrix with entries $[\overrightarrow{v_1}]_B ...[\overrightarrow{v_k}]_B$

Comment: It looks like this works, but you don't really need to go through coordinate vectors (although it's ok to do that).

Comment: What would be a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: It's essentially the same as what you wrote, you just don't need $\begin{bmatrix}\vec{v}_i\end{bmatrix}_B$.  You have already written the columns of $A$ as linear combinations of the $\vec{u}_i$'s, so since the $j$th column of $BX$ is $B\vec{x}_j$, you can jump to that the columns of $X$ are $(c_{j1},\cdots,c_{jk})$.

Answer (score 2):

You have to take the sum and consider the span.

Also consider rewriting the product. Change of base